# Measure to get the number of parent issues only if their subtask is in specific status in EazyBi for Jira Cloud

Tags: jira

I am struggling with MDX and custom measures.
I am looking to create a custom measure that would return the number of issues (from issue created), but only if those issues have a subtask (of type “deployment”) that is either in status “A” or “B”
I believe in need to use the Filter function somehow but really have no clue.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you need the `Filter()` function to refine the *Issue* dimension member set and retrieve parent issues with the specific sub-tasks. The calculated measure formula could look similar to the one below:

```
Sum(
  Filter(
    Descendants([Issue].CurrentMember,[Issue].[Issue]),
    -- issues with sub-tasks
    Not IsEmpty([Issue].CurrentMember.Get('Sub-task keys'))
  ),
  CASE WHEN 
    -- number of Deployment type sub-tasks in A or B statuses
    Sum(
      -- get the parent sub-tasks as a set of issues
      [Issue].[Issue].GetMembersByKeys(
        [Issue].CurrentMember.Get('Sub-task keys')
      ),
      -- retrieve how many of the sub-tasks are in the desired statuses and type
      Aggregate(
      {[Status].[A],
      [Status].[B]},
      ([Measures].[Issues created].[Deployment])
    ) > 0
  THEN
    1
  END
)
```

See the eazyBI function reference for more details about the used functions - https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybi/analyze-and-visualize/calculated-measures-and-members/mdx-function-reference.

I recommend posting on the eazyBI community site for eazyBI-specific questions - https://community.eazybi.com.